# As an non EU applicant can i study masters in switzerland and search for jobs in Germany?

Tags: eu

As an non EU applicant,Is it possible to study Masters in Switzerland and search for job oppurtunites in Germany and other EU countries?

Comment: Questions about long-term migration including study and work belong on [expatriates.se].  FWIW, you can study in Switzerland and search for work wherever you like, but when you find work you'll still need to apply for an appropriate visa or work permit from your chosen country, whether or not it's part of the EU

Comment: @Arthur'sPass, I believe this question is about short-term travel within Schengen while on a long-term visa in Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Justa confirmation,If we get selected in other EU countries,we still need to apply for work visa for that particular countries right???

Comment: @Srinaath, yes, you will need a new long-term visa for *exactly* that country. Depending on the job and pay, you may qualify for a Blue Card. But that is better asked on Expatriates SE.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal conditions, a long-term national visa from *one* Schengen state allows you to visit the *other* Schengen states as if you had a multiple-entry Schengen visa with the same duration. The 90/180 rule applies to the *other* Schengen states.

Looking for jobs and having interviews are permitted activities in the other states. Actually working is not.

Right now there are potential disruptions because of the COVID pandemic. Restrictions which are being lifted may be reintroduced if there are breakouts.